# Implement geometric constraint using DOCplex

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, python, docplex, geometric-programming

currently I'm working on a wind farm layout optimization problem. I found an appropriate model in literature (Fischetti et al.) and now I'm trying to reproduce it using the Python API of cplex with DOCPlex.
The model looks like the following:

$\begin{align}
\text{max} \  z = \sum_{i \in V} (P_i x_i - w_i)
\end{align}$

s.t.

$\begin{align}
N_ {min} \le \sum_{i \in V} x_i \le N_{max} \\\\
x_i + x_j \le 1 \qquad (i,j) \in E_I \tag{eqn of interest}\\\\
\sum_{j \in V} I_{i,j} x_j \le w_i + M_i (1-x_i) \quad i \in V \\\\
w_i \in \{0,1\} \quad i \in V \\\\
w_i \ge 0 \quad i \in V
\end{align}$

with the corresponding set $E_I$:
$\begin{equation}
\{(i,j): i,j \in V, dist(i,j) < D_{min}, i \neq j\}
\end{equation}$

From my understanding, this constraint ensures the mininum distance $D_{min}$ is achieved by comparing the current iterator $i$ with all already set locations $x_j$ in the distance of $D_{min}$. If there would be a match, the eqn $x_i + x_j$ would be at least 2 (if the binary at $i$ would be set), violating the constraint.
I am currently failing to add this constraint to my model in DOCcplex. If anyone could help my, by giving me a hint I would be glad.

Thank you in advance